# Using MFA after DBT upgrade to version 1.1.1 to connect snowflake

Tags: upgrade, dbt, multi-factor-authentication

I have recently upgraded dbt to 1.1.1 version but I am facing an issue where when I run dbt compile for a single model it is throwing multiple push notifications on duo
which wasn't the case earlier in my local virtual environment setup.
For one model it used to send only one push notification before dbt upgrade.
I do not wish to remove MFA completely but can someone please provide any information on how to handle this scenario. What are the best practices on using MFA to connect to snowflake from DBT?

Regards
Ashsc

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/warehouse-profiles/snowflake-profile#user--password--duo-mfa-authentication) on Snowflake + DUO:

> Along with adding the authenticator parameter, be sure to run `alter account set allow_client_mfa_caching = true;` in your Snowflake warehouse. Together, these will allow you to easily verify authenatication with the DUO Mobile app (skipping this results in push notifications for every model built on every dbt run).